# How to properly update Mesa drivers?

Tags: debian, apt, intel-graphics, mesa

I need OpenGL 4.5 to be supported by my graphics card's driver, and as far as I know Mesa is actually able to run it.
`glxinfo` gives me this:

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So this means it can only run OpenGL 3.0. So I tried to update it, but I ran into several problems:

If I try to update it through `apt`, i.e. `sudo apt-get upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri -t testing`, it is broken:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri -t testing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-va-drivers : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-va-drivers:i386 : Depends: libsensors4:i386 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Okay, but:

```
$ apt-cache policy libsensors4
libsensors4:
  Installed: 1:3.4.0-4
  Candidate: 1:3.4.0-4
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.4.0-4 900
        900 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So it depends on the lib version >=1:3.0.0, but I have version 1:3.4.0-4, which is really strange.

Generally, I don't understand how should I upgrade Mesa. If using `apt`, I don't know which packages should I update. If from source, I don't know how will it interact with `apt` and if it won't be reverted by an update.

I am using Debian 9 Stretch, and my graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 5000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to install testing directly on stable! or you'll end up with a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) (at best) or will lose a lot of packages due to unrealistic dependencies.

The good news is that those updated packages [are available](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/libgl1-mesa-dri) in [`stretch-backports`](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/). Debian's mesa had several packaging changes in testing so also in stretch-backports, related to the [vendor neutral's GL dispatch library](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/libglvnd0) turning this non-trivial. Also, since you are using multi-arch with both `amd64` and `i386` packages, *those packages must be upgraded in lockstep* or you'll get some of the errors you've seen.

I thus can't tell the exact command on how to upgrade mesa only, without upgrading everything (which you should *not* do: `stretch-backports` doesn't have security support) but I will give a procedure.

First please follow [Debian's instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) on how to add `stretch-backports` properly. I'll put a simplified summary here:

```
# echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
# apt-get update
```

And DO remove buster/testing/sid entries if you added them.

Some packages might have disappeared (eg `libgles1-mesa` isn't provided anymore) and others appeared. You will have to upgrade all involved packages in *one* single apt-get command, so you'd first have to look at the most involved packages with their current version, and let the dependency resolver pick the missing parts (eg: `libdrm2`). You should do things manually, not in a script because you have to check nothing bad happens (like `apt-get` offering to delete 100 packages). So something like this:

```
dpkg -l | fgrep 13.0.6-1+b2
```

or even:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ && $3 == "13.0.6-1+b2" { print $2 }' | xargs
```

to get the main part of the list of packages. DO NOTE that for installed multi-arch packages you must provide both the `amd64` package (which is by default so doesn't require the extra `:amd64` but you can leave it from the cut/paste) and *again* the same `i386` package (using `:i386` appended to the package name) if it was also found in the previous `dpkg` command. So the final installation command should probably look like:

```
apt-get -t stretch-backports install libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 mesa-opencl-icd:amd64 mesa-opencl-icd:i386 ...
```

You get the idea. Now check the number of *to be removed* packages that are offered. If there are some mesa related packages to be removed (eg: `libgles1-mesa`) that's fine, if most of them or many unrelated packages are offered to be removed, abort and ponder what might be missing. Of course many others should be offered in addition as upgrade (eg: `libdrm2` and `libdrm2:i386`). It's probably those that might still cause trouble because of multi-arch, so you might have to add them manually twice (once for each arch) to the growing one-liner list if `apt-get` isn't smart enough.

As suggested by @Stephen Kitt, other useful and related packages, dealing with an improved usage of the hardware, including graphics support, are also available in stretch-backports, and should probably also be upgraded. Among them:

- `linux-image-amd64` which will currently pull `linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64`
- Various firmware packages (anyway all those that are currently installed should be upgraded), like `firmware-misc-nonfree` which might include upgraded graphical support and anyway which might have to be upgraded as a (perhaps hidden) dependency for the newer kernel for best results.

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478949/86440) for a recipe to upgrade all currently installed Mesa packages to the backported version.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if my answer is still that useful now

Comment: Yours explains how to add the backport repo, which is useful. You could also mention that a newer kernel from backports would help too, along with the matching firmware.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks, your solution worked. This answer still can be counted as the correct one since it has the right idea.

Comment: What's the update procedure when there aren't `mesa` packages in backports?

Comment: @genpfault: you can rebuild packages from [Debian unstable source](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/mesa) or from [Debian git source](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/lib/mesa) (or even adapt from upstream source + modified debian/ subdir from previous). As usual you might have to recursively build (build-)dependencies. Some wiki pages (to adapt to the case): [BuildingTutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial), [SimpleBackportCreation](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation). Someone else might give a better answer in an actual question rather than comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the event Mesa & co. aren't in backports you can build from source:

#### [Schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) Setup

---

1. Host setup:

   ```
   sudo apt install --yes schroot debootstrap
   ```
2. Make directories for schroots:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/debian32
   sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/debian64
   ```
3. Create & populate config files for schroots:

   ```
   # /etc/schroot/chroot.d/debian32.conf
   [debian32]
   description=Debian i386
   directory=/srv/chroot/debian32
   personality=linux32
   type=directory
   users=yourusername

   # /etc/schroot/chroot.d/debian64.conf
   [debian64]
   description=Debian amd64
   directory=/srv/chroot/debian64
   personality=linux
   type=directory
   users=yourusername
   ```
4. Add `/usr/local` to `/etc/schroot/default/fstab` so that the build scripts inside the schroots can install files there:

   ```
   /usr/local    /usr/local    none    rw,bind    0    0
   ```
5. Populate schroot directories with Debian installs:

   ```
   # install debian in schroots
   sudo debootstrap --arch=i386 $(lsb_release --short --codename) /srv/chroot/debian32
   sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 $(lsb_release --short --codename) /srv/chroot/debian64

   # add deb-src lines to sources.list
   echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian $(lsb_release --short --codename) main" | sudo tee --append /srv/chroot/debian32/etc/apt/sources.list
   echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian $(lsb_release --short --codename) main" | sudo tee --append /srv/chroot/debian64/etc/apt/sources.list

   # install sudo in schroots:
   sudo schroot -c debian32 -- apt install --yes sudo
   sudo schroot -c debian64 -- apt install --yes sudo

   # update package lists:
   sudo schroot -c debian32 -- apt update
   sudo schroot -c debian64 -- apt update
   ```

#### Compilation

---

On the host system, clone the source repositories:

```
# set source directory
export SRC=$HOME/mesa-sources

# install git
sudo apt install --yes git

# these branches/tags Work For Me™ on Debian 11 for a RX 6700 XT.
mkdir -p $SRC && \
cd $SRC && \
git clone --branch 1.20.0         https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland.git && \
git clone --branch 1.25           https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland-protocols.git && \
git clone --branch libdrm-2.4.110 https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm.git && \
git clone --branch mesa-22.0.2    https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa.git && \
git clone --branch 20220411       https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git && \
git clone --branch v5.17.4        https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git $SRC/linux-src/linux

# grab host kernel config
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) $SRC/linux-src/linux/.config
```

Then enter each schroot in turn with `schroot -c debian32`/`schroot -c debian64` and do the following:

1. Install build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt build-dep --yes wayland wayland-protocols libdrm mesa linux && \
   sudo apt install --yes cmake meson
   ```
2. Set up environment variables:

   ```
   export SRC=$HOME/mesa-sources
   export PREFIX=/usr/local
   ```
3. Install `wayland`:

   ```
   cd $SRC/wayland && \
   meson build-$HOSTTYPE --prefix=$PREFIX --buildtype=release \
   -D documentation=false && \
   ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE && sudo ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE install
   ```
4. Install `wayland-protocols`:

   ```
   cd $SRC/wayland-protocols && \
   meson build-$HOSTTYPE --prefix=$PREFIX --buildtype=release && \
   ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE && sudo ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE install
   ```
5. Install `drm`:

   ```
   cd $SRC/drm && \
   meson build-$HOSTTYPE --prefix=$PREFIX --buildtype=release && \
   ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE && sudo ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE install
   ```
6. Install `mesa`:

   ```
   cd $SRC/mesa && \
   meson build-$HOSTTYPE --prefix=$PREFIX --buildtype=release \
   -D gallium-vdpau=enabled \
   -D shared-llvm=disabled \
   -D vulkan-layers=device-select,intel-nullhw,overlay && \
   ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE && sudo ninja -C build-$HOSTTYPE install
   ```
7. (64-bit schroot only) Compile kernel (with integrated AMD and Intel GPU firmware):

   ```
   # collect firmware
   cd $SRC/linux-firmware && \
   ./copy-firmware.sh $SRC/linux-firmware-bin

   # compile linux & generate Debian packages
   cd $SRC/linux-src/linux && \
   ./scripts/config --set-val DEBUG_INFO n && \
   ./scripts/config --set-str EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR $SRC/linux-firmware-bin && \
   ./scripts/config --set-str EXTRA_FIRMWARE "$(cd $SRC/linux-firmware-bin; find * -type f | grep -E "amdgpu/|i915/" | paste -sd " " -)" && \
   yes "" | make oldconfig && \
   make -j$(nproc) bindeb-pkg
   ```

   While compiling in (nearly) *all* the firmware is [technically possible](https://superuser.com/a/1718216/10737) I would recommend against it.

#### Install Packages On Host

---

Back on the host system do the following:

1. Host setup:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
   sudo apt update && \
   sudo apt install --yes apt-file gcc-multilib && \
   sudo apt-file update
   ```
2. Scan `/usr/local` for missing libraries & install the packages that provide them:

   ```
   # 64-bit
   sudo apt install --yes $(\
   find /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -type f -exec ldd {} \; | \
   grep "not found" | \
   awk '{print "x86_64-linux-gnu/" $1 "$"}' | \
   sort | uniq | \
   apt-file --regexp --from-file search - | \
   awk -v ORS=" " -F ":" '{print $1}' )

   # 32-bit
   sudo apt install --yes $(\
   find /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ -type f -exec ldd {} \; | \
   grep "not found" | \
   awk '{print "i386-linux-gnu/" $1 "$"}' | \
   sort | uniq | \
   apt-file --architecture i386 --regexp --from-file search - | \
   awk -v ORS=" " -F ":" '{print $1 ":i386"}' )
   ```
3. Install kernel packages:

   ```
   # set source directory
   export SRC=$HOME/mesa-sources && \
   sudo dpkg -i $SRC/linux-src/linux-headers-*.deb && \
   sudo dpkg -i $SRC/linux-src/linux-image-*.deb && \
   sudo dpkg -i $SRC/linux-src/linux-libc-dev*.deb
   ```

#### System Setup

---

1. Add a `profile.d` script to ensure (most) shells and shell types use the new DRI drivers:

   ```
   # /etc/profile.d/local-mesa.sh
   export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri
   ```
2. Add a systemd config override so that when KDE's SDDM starts Xorg AIGLX also uses the new DRI drivers:

   ```
   # /etc/systemd/system/sddm.service.d/local-mesa.conf
   [Service]
   Environment="LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri"
   ```

   (Greeters from other desktop environments require the same config file in the corresponding `service.d` directories)
3. (Optional) Remove old Mesa Vulkan driver:

   ```
   sudo apt remove mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
   ```

   This prevents the Vulkan loader from picking up the old Debian-provided Vulkan driver files (if any) and possibly returning one of them as the "first" GPU.

   While Mesa *does* have the [`MESA_VK_DEVICE_SELECT`](https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#vulkan-mesa-device-select-layer-environment-variables) environment variable to help re-order the device list it only lets you choose a particular PCI device to prioritize, not choose between multiple drivers for the *same* device.  If you want to leave the Debian-provided Vulkan drivers installed and need to choose between them try [vkdevicechooser](https://github.com/aejsmith/vkdevicechooser).
4. Finally, reboot to:

   - Load the new `amdgpu` kernel module & firmware
   - Refresh the `ldconfig` cache
   - Force systemd to load the new unit override for SDDM
   - Restart Xorg so it can pick up the new DRI libraries

Answer (score 0):

In the event Mesa & co. aren't in backports you can create backported packages yourself:

#### Setup

---

1. Set environment variables:

   ```
   # point this somewhere convenient, needs ~23 GiB of space
   export MESA_SRC=$HOME/mesa-backports

   # it *is* possible to build mesa with bullseye's llvm-toolchain-11,
   # albeit with a slightly more involved patch for mesa
   export MESA_PACKAGES="\
   wayland \
   wayland-protocols \
   libdrm \
   directx-headers \
   llvm-toolchain-14 \
   mesa \
   firmware-nonfree"
   ```
2. Install [proot](https://github.com/proot-me/proot) from source (due to [bug#1011348](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1011348)):

   ```
   sudo apt install curl && \
   sudo apt build-dep proot && \
   mkdir -p $MESA_SRC && cd $MESA_SRC && \
   curl -L "https://github.com/proot-me/proot/archive/refs/tags/v5.3.1.tar.gz" | tar xzf - && \
   cd proot-*/ && 
   make -C src loader.elf loader-m32.elf build.h && \
   make -C src proot && \
   sudo make -C src install
   ```

#### Chroots

---

1. Set up i386 & amd64 chroots using [mmdebstrap](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/mmdebstrap/mmdebstrap.1.en.html):

   ```
   sudo apt install mmdebstrap && \
   time \
   for ARCH in i386 amd64; do \
   mkdir -p $MESA_SRC && cd $MESA_SRC && \
   mmdebstrap --mode=proot --format=directory --arch=$ARCH bullseye debian-$ARCH && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH apt update && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH apt install --yes locales eatmydata && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH sh -c 'echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen' && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH /usr/sbin/locale-gen && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH eatmydata apt install --yes \
   devscripts equivs local-apt-repository && \
   proot -S debian-$ARCH mkdir -p /srv/local-apt-repository ; \
   done
   ```

#### Sources

---

1. Add [sources](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage) for `unstable`:

   ```
   { sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable-sources.list > /dev/null << HEREDOCDELIM
   deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
   HEREDOCDELIM
   } && \
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Download source packages & update changelogs:

   ```
   for PKG in $MESA_PACKAGES; do \
   mkdir -p $MESA_SRC/$PKG && cd $MESA_SRC/$PKG && \
   apt source $PKG/unstable && \
   cd $MESA_SRC/$PKG/$PKG-*/ && \
   DEBFULLNAME="Example User" \
   DEBEMAIL="user@example.com" \
   dch --bpo " " ; \
   done
   ```
3. Apply patches:

   ```
   cd $MESA_SRC/firmware-nonfree/firmware-nonfree-*/ && \
   { base64 -d << 'HEREDOCDELIM'
   LS0tIGEvZGViaWFuL3J1bGVzCisrKyBiL2RlYmlhbi9ydWxlcwpAQCAtMzgsMTQgKzM4LDYgQEAK
   IAlta2RpciAtcCAkKEBEKQogCXByaW50ZiA+JEAgJ1NvdXJjZTogJXNcblZlcnNpb246ICVzXG4n
   ICQoU09VUkNFKSAkKFZFUlNJT05fU09VUkNFKQogCi1kZWJpYW4vY29udHJvbCBkZWJpYW4vcnVs
   ZXMuZ2VuOiAkKEdFTkNPTlRST0wpICQoQ09OVFJPTF9GSUxFUykKLWlmZXEgKCQod2lsZGNhcmQg
   ZGViaWFuL2NvbnRyb2wubWQ1c3VtKSwpCi0JJChNQUtFKSAtZiBkZWJpYW4vcnVsZXMgZGViaWFu
   L2NvbnRyb2wtcmVhbAotZWxzZQotCW1kNXN1bSAtLWNoZWNrIGRlYmlhbi9jb250cm9sLm1kNXN1
   bSAtLXN0YXR1cyB8fCBcCi0JCSQoTUFLRSkgLWYgZGViaWFuL3J1bGVzIGRlYmlhbi9jb250cm9s
   LXJlYWwKLWVuZGlmCi0KIGRlYmlhbi9jb250cm9sLXJlYWw6ICQoR0VOQ09OVFJPTCkgJChDT05U
   Uk9MX0ZJTEVTKQogIyBXZSBjdXJyZW50bHkgbmVlZCB0byBydW4gY29weS1maXJtd2FyZS5zaCB0
   byBnZXQgYSBjb21wbGV0ZSBsaXN0IG9mCiAjIHN5bWxpbmtzIHRvIGluY2x1ZGUgaW4gcGFja2Fn
   ZSBkZXNjcmlwdGlvbnMuCg==
   HEREDOCDELIM
   } | patch -p1 && \
   cd $MESA_SRC/mesa/mesa-*/ && \
   { base64 -d << 'HEREDOCDELIM'
   LS0tIGEvZGViaWFuL2NvbnRyb2wKKysrIGIvZGViaWFuL2NvbnRyb2wKQEAgLTQxNSw3ICs0MTUs
   NyBAQAogQXJjaGl0ZWN0dXJlOiBhbWQ2NCBhcm02NCBhcm1lbCBhcm1oZiBpMzg2IG1pcHM2NGVs
   IG1pcHNlbCBwb3dlcnBjIHBwYzY0IHBwYzY0ZWwgczM5MHggc3BhcmM2NAogUHJlLURlcGVuZHM6
   ICR7bWlzYzpQcmUtRGVwZW5kc30KIERlcGVuZHM6Ci0gbGliY2xjLTEzLAorIGxpYmNsYy0xNCwK
   ICBvY2wtaWNkLWxpYm9wZW5jbDEgfCBsaWJvcGVuY2wxLAogICR7c2hsaWJzOkRlcGVuZHN9LAog
   ICR7bWlzYzpEZXBlbmRzfSwK
   HEREDOCDELIM
   } | patch -p1
   ```

   (Apologies for the opaque [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) blobs, the firmware-nonfree patch needed tabs but [Markdown code blocks eat tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181828) and even if you fixed that [pasting tab-containing text into a Bash prompt causes it to consume the tabs while trying to tab-complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208848/) :()

#### Build

---

1. Build packages (takes ~90 minutes on a 12-core Ryzen 5900x):

   ```
   time \
   for ARCH in i386 amd64; do \
   for PKG in $MESA_PACKAGES; do \
   cd $MESA_SRC/$PKG/$PKG-*/ && \
   proot -S $MESA_SRC/debian-$ARCH /usr/lib/local-apt-repository/rebuild && \
   proot -S $MESA_SRC/debian-$ARCH apt update && \
   PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH \
   proot -S $MESA_SRC/debian-$ARCH eatmydata mk-build-deps --install --remove \
   --tool='apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes --no-install-recommends --yes' && \
   DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="nostrip nocheck nodoc noautodbgsym noddebs" \
   DEB_BUILD_PROFILES="nostrip nocheck nodoc noautodbgsym noddebs" \
   proot -R $MESA_SRC/debian-$ARCH dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary -us -uc && \
   proot -S $MESA_SRC/debian-$ARCH cp ../*.deb /srv/local-apt-repository \
   ; done \
   ; done
   ```
2. Copy packages into the [local-apt-repository](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/local-apt-repository) package depot (needs ~1 GiB):

   ```
   sudo apt install local-apt-repository && \
   sudo mkdir -p /srv/local-apt-repository && \
   for PKG in $MESA_PACKAGES; do \
   sudo cp $MESA_SRC/$PKG/*.deb /srv/local-apt-repository/ \
   ; done && \
   sudo /usr/lib/local-apt-repository/rebuild
   ```

#### Upgrade

---

1. Upgrade to the new packages:

   ```
   sudo apt update && \
   sudo apt upgrade -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"
   ```
2. Install kernel from backports:

   ```
   { sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye-backports.list > /dev/null << HEREDOCDELIM
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
   HEREDOCDELIM
   } && \
   sudo apt update && \
   sudo apt install linux-image-amd64/bullseye-backports
   ```
3. Reboot