# How to update MESA for a higher supported OpenGL version?

Tags: debian, opengl, mesa

I am running Debian 10 buster and I need a higher OpenGL version for an application to run. Here is what I get as an output when I search for my MESA version:  "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.3.6
" Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is likely to be a hardware limitation rather than a Mesa limitation; Mesa in Debian 10 supports OpenGL 4.5 on capable hardware. What hardware are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly update Mesa drivers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509487/how-to-properly-update-mesa-drivers)